# firebase in flutter conflicts all the dependencies

Tags: firebase, flutter-dependencies, flutter

I am creating ChatApp in flutter using firebase. After upgrading **flutter SDK with 2.0.1** and all firebase dependencies with the latest versions, I am getting some conflicts.

here is the list of dependencies I am using

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.0
  data_connection_checker: ^0.3.4
  country_pickers: ^1.3.0
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+3
  cached_network_image: ^2.5.0
  url_launcher: ^5.7.0
  device_calendar: ^3.1.0
  intl: ^0.17.0

  firebase_core: ^1.0.0
  firebase_analytics: ^7.1.0
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.0
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.0
  firebase_storage: ^8.0.0

  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12
  permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
  contacts_service: ^0.4.6
```

if I use the above versions, I am getting this error on `pub get`

```
Because firebase_storage >=8.0.0 depends on firebase_storage_web ^1.0.0 which depends on http ^0.13.0, firebase_storage >=8.0.0 requires http ^0.13.0.
And because cached_network_image >=2.5.0 <3.0.0-nullsafety depends on flutter_cache_manager ^2.1.0 which depends on http ^0.12.0+2, firebase_storage >=8.0.0 is incompatible with cached_network_image >=2.5.0 <3.0.0-nullsafety.
So, because ChatApp depends on both cached_network_image ^2.5.0 and firebase_storage ^8.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because ChatApp depends on both cached_network_image ^2.5.0 and firebase_storage ^8.0.0, version solving failed.)
```

Now I am adding `http`

```
http: ^0.13.0
```

and the error is

```
Because cached_network_image >=2.5.0 <3.0.0-nullsafety depends on flutter_cache_manager ^2.1.0 which depends on http ^0.12.0+2, cached_network_image >=2.5.0 <3.0.0-nullsafety requires http ^0.12.0+2.
So, because ChatApp depends on both cached_network_image ^2.5.0 and http ^0.13.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because ChatApp depends on both cached_network_image ^2.5.0 and http ^0.13.0, version solving failed.)
```

if I change `cached_network_image`  to

```
cached_network_image: ^3.0.0-nullsafety
```

the error is

```
Because every version of firebase_analytics_web depends on firebase ^7.3.0 which depends on http >=0.11.3 <0.13.0, every version of firebase_analytics_web requires http >=0.11.3 <0.13.0.
And because firebase_analytics >=7.1.0 depends on firebase_analytics_web ^0.2.0, firebase_analytics >=7.1.0 requires http >=0.11.3 <0.13.0.
So, because ChatApp depends on both firebase_analytics ^7.1.0 and http ^0.13.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because ChatApp depends on both firebase_analytics ^7.1.0 and http ^0.13.0, version solving failed.)
```

and so on...

does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: try lower version of firebase dependencies

Comment: @HamzaSiddiqui, thx, downgrading flutter working for me

Comment: may this helps you:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67052468/resolving-dependencies-pub-finished-with-exit-code-1/67058612#67058612

Answer (score 1):

Below command analyze dependency version within using packages and suggest 'Resolvable' packges version.

```
flutter pub outdated
```