# Resolving dependencies: pub finished with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have this dependency conflict:

```
$ flutter pub upgrade --dry-run
Resolving dependencies...
Because image >=2.1.14 <3.0.0-nullsafety.0 depends on archive ^2.0.0 and image >=2.0.4 <2.1.14 depends on archive >=1.0.16 <3.0.0, image >=2.0.4 <3.0.0-nullsafety.0 requires archive >=1.0.16 <3.0.0.
And because flutter_launcher_icons >=0.7.1 <0.9.0 depends on image ^2.1.1 and every version of flutter_driver from sdk depends on archive 3.1.2, flutter_launcher_icons >=0.7.1 <0.9.0 is incompatible with flutter_driver from sdk.
So, because gallery depends on both flutter_driver any from sdk and flutter_launcher_icons ^0.8.1, version solving failed.
pub finished with exit code 1
```

#### Versions

```
$ dart --version
Dart SDK version: 2.13.0-222.0.dev (dev) (Fri Apr 9 12:15:17 2021 -0700) on "macos_x64"
```

```
$ flutter --version
Flutter 2.1.0-13.0.pre.574 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter
Framework • revision 02efffc134 (2 days ago) • 2021-04-10 03:49:01 -0400
Engine • revision 8863afff16
Tools • Dart 2.13.0 (build 2.13.0-222.0.dev)
```

#### pubspec.yaml

```
name: gallery
description: A resource to help developers evaluate and use Flutter.
repository: https://github.com/flutter/gallery
version: 2.8.1+020801

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ">=0.16.1 <=0.17.0"
  flutter_localized_locales: ">=1.1.1 <=2.0.0"
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  rally_assets: ^2.0.0
  meta: ^1.1.8
  scoped_model: ^1.1.0
  shrine_images: ^1.1.2
  url_launcher: ^5.6.0
  vector_math: ^2.0.8
  collection: ^1.14.0
  flutter_gallery_assets: ^0.2.6
  package_info: ^0.4.0
  google_fonts: ^1.1.2
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.3.3
  animations: ^1.1.2
  provider: ^4.3.2
  adaptive_breakpoints: ^0.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_driver:
    sdk: flutter
  test:
  path:
  args:
  grinder: ^0.8.0
  pedantic: ^1.9.0
  string_scanner: ^1.0.5
  web_benchmarks: ^0.0.3
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.8.1"

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/images/logo/roof.png"

flutter:
  assets:
    - packages/flutter_gallery_assets/assets/studies/shrine_card_dark.png
    - ...

...
```

#### Tried

I changed:

```
flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.8.1"
```

to:

```
flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.9.0"
```

But it couldn't help.

#### Question

I cannot figure out how to resolve the conflict. Is there a standard way for such conflict resolutions which I might be missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can run in your project terminal

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

Answer (score 4):

Because your project depends on `flutter_launcher_icons` and `flutter_driver`
and both packages depend on the third package `archive` with different versions.

flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.8.1" depends on `archive: ">=2.0.4 <3.0.0-nullsafety.0"` and `flutter_driver` from sdk depends on `archive: 3.1.2`, So there is conflict of resolving version of `archive` package.

So to resolve this conflict you have to add the manual entry in pubspec.yaml file of your project.

```
dependency_overrides:
  archive: 3.1.2  //any version you want for resolution.
```

And to know how to flutter resolves dependencies, check the below link.
https://medium.com/cashify-engineering/flutter-dependencies-resolution-2faecdbfce03

this link also describes a standard way of resolving such dependency conflict.